Is there a direct way to define the request and translate the response in a certain language?
I'm creating a chatbot using OpenAI and AISearch. Below is the request code. Now I wanted to translate my request and received a translated response based from a certain language.Aside using Language translator service. Is there any way using only OpenAI and AISearch?
var chatClient = AzureOpenAIClient.GetChatClient(AzureOpenAIDeploymentModel);
ChatCompletionOptions ??= new ChatCompletionOptions()
{
    MaxOutputTokenCount = TokenCount,
    Temperature = Constants.TEMPERATURE,
    TopP = Constants.TOPP,
    PresencePenalty = Constants.PRESENCEPENALTY,
    FrequencyPenalty = Constants.FREQUENCYPENALTY
};

ChatCompletionOptions.AddDataSource(new AzureSearchChatDataSource()
    {
        IndexName = AISearchIndexName,
        Authentication = DataSourceAuthentication.FromSystemManagedIdentity(),
        Endpoint = new Uri(AISearchServiceEndpointURL!),
        QueryType = DataSourceQueryType.Semantic,
        SemanticConfiguration = base.SemanticSearchConfiguration
    });
}
    
var completion = await chatClient.CompleteChatAsync(conversationMessages, ChatCompletionOptions);


I'm not quite understanding your question, basically OpenAI you can prompt for specific language to be translated, and it returns well. AI Search involves for getting information, if you need that information to be translated, request one more time to OpenAI to translate.

You give it in prompt correctly. It will translate and process it.

You add the prompt for translating the language.
Example like below.
{
        "role": "system",
        "content": "Translate the input query to English, process the query in English, and provide a response. Ensure that the translation is accurate and that the response addresses the user's needs."
    }

And the output for below query, it is in Kannada language.
ಕುವೆಂಪು ಅವರ ಜೀವನ ಚರಿತ್ರೆ ಪ್ರಬಂಧ.
Output:
Translation: Essay on the biography of Kuvempu.  
  
Response: Kuvempu was a renowned poet, writer, and philosopher from Karnataka, India. He was born on December 29, 1904, and passed away on November 11, 1994. Kuvempu's life and works have had a significant impact on Kannada literature and culture. His notable works include "Malegalalli Madumagalu," "Shri Ramayana Darshanam," and "Kanooru Heggadithi." Kuvempu was also a recipient of numerous awards, including the Padma Vibhushan and the Jnanpith Award. An essay on Kuvempu's biography would cover his early life, education, literary works, and contributions to Kannada literature and culture.

Output:

Similarly, you build the prompt on your use case.
